# Disable select on an overlay layer in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, overlays

Is anyone aware of how to prevent an overlay layer from being selectable?  I'm using a basemap from an external source and have added a (polygon) kml layer that I need to display (and allow people to hide), but I don't want them to be selecting that layer rather than the points and lines I have on top of it.

Comment: What do you mean by selectable? If I'm not mistaken it should only be interactive in some way if you added an event handler to the layer?

Comment: Hmm - you are likely correct.  I'm new to openlayers, and am using a somewhat modified version of it - https://github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew/wiki/Geomap.  In the version I'm using, the overlays can be added with a number of options.  By default (perhaps) all overlays can be selected.
*NINJA-EDIT* Given that my case is unusual, I'm not sure I'm going to be able to get help.  There's lots of overlap, but perhaps not in this case....

Comment: Maybe the "popups" option of overlays defaults to true with Geomap? Not a qualified answer, just a guess.